# Not able to convert a String to json Array and parse

Tags: java, json, parsing

i have stuck with String ,json convertion and parsing . it may look silly but i am help less.

here is my response from server which is string

```
[{
  "ClientName":"SELVI",
  "AccountID":"2040IG20000185",
  "ToatalLonaAmount":"35000.0000",
  "RepaymentFequencyID":"M",
  "RepaymentFequency":"Monthly",
  "InterestRate":"25.88",
  "EMIAmount":"1883.0000",
  "PrincipleOutstanding":"3626.0000",
  "InterestOutstanding":"108.0000",
  "TotalTerm":"24",
  "RemainingTerm":"2",
  "ErrorCode":"",
  "Response":true,
  "ResponseMsg":"",
  "Status":"1",
  "LoanStatusID":"A",
  "LoanStatus":"Active Loan"
}]
```

how can i parse it and read values ?

please help me with this. it looks like json array i'm very new to this.

i have tried this but not able to read values

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj1  = parser.parse(response.toString());
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(obj1);

//JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("data :"+array.get(i));          
}
```

Comment: You should find out what obj1 is. You can probably cast it to JSONArray.

Comment: i have tried it but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got solution like below

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();  
                Object obj1  = parser.parse(response.toString());
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                array=(JSONArray) obj1;
                ResponseModel r= new Gson().fromJson(array.get(0).toString(), ResponseModel.class);
                System.out.println(r.getClientName());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with JSON.parse(jsonValue);

Here is the example:

```js
var json = '[{"ClientName":"SELVI","AccountID":"2040IG20000185","ToatalLonaAmount":"35000.0000","RepaymentFequencyID":"M","RepaymentFequency":"Monthly","InterestRate":"25.88","EMIAmount":"1883.0000","PrincipleOutstanding":"3626.0000","InterestOutstanding":"108.0000","TotalTerm":"24","RemainingTerm":"2","ErrorCode":"","Response":true,"ResponseMsg":"","Status":"1","LoanStatusID":"A","LoanStatus":"Active Loan"}]'

var objArr = JSON.parse(json);

for(var i=0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
  console.log("Object from array: ", objArr[i])
}
```

Comment: no problems, you can try out my solution as well if you have time and mark it as solved if it works, so it helps others if they have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

you can simply bind it into POJO with `fasterxml.jackson` library. Just create class with fields sutable to attributes in json, e.g.

```
public class MyBindClass{
    @JsonProperty(value = "ClientName")
    private String clientName;
    @JsonProperty(value = "AccountID")
    private String accountId; 
    //etc
    //getters and setters here

}
```

and then you can bind your json string into list of such objects (as your json contains list):

```
List<MyBindClass> myBindClassList = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<MyBindClass>>(){});
```